# How can I add more image sliders on a parallax website?

Tags: parallax

I'm busy with an update for my website. At the moment I have this: http://thijmtu141.141.axc.nl/. When you go to portfolio and you click there you see my portfolio page. I would like to put an image slider on every page (graphic design, photographic, art, film) next to the text. I have tried a lot but nothing has worked. Does anyone know a solution to help me?

Thanks,

Thijmen

p.s. Sorry for my bad English I'm from the Netherlands.